# hide country code in react-phone-number-input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when phone number has initial value, With country <select/>
In the input box, I only want to show Phone number as for code i am using flags, so i don't want the country code to be shown.

current output(input field): +91 9999999999

required output(input field): 9999999999

[refrence link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/currying-frog-pxzbuo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Note: `displayInitialValueAsLocalNumber` converts country code to `0` for India country,
Input field should contain only phone Number
Ex: 99999 99999

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.